# How to do this tricky down-casting with generic constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to downcast a controller instance inside an action filter, and I'm having issue doing so.

I have a `DefaultController` class:

```
public abstract partial class DefaultController<T> : Controller where T : IBaseEntity
{

}
```

`IBaseEntity` is:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    int OwnerId { get; set; }

}
```

I have an instance of a controller, inheriting the `DefaultController`:

```
public class WorkflowController : DefaultController<Workflow>
{
}
```

`Workflow` is inheriting `BaseEntity` which implements `IBaseEntity`.

Now, inside my action filter, code wise, it's impossible to know on which controller the request is running on so I'm trying to downcast it to `DefaultController`

```
public class AddHeaders : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var defaultControllerGenericType = controller.GetType().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
        //this retrieve with which type DefaultController was initiated with...
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as DefaultController<BaseEntity>; 
        //this returns null...
        var controller2 = filterContext.Controller as DefaultController<IBaseEntity>;
        //this does so as well.

    }
}
```

I've tried using `defaultControllerGenericType` but I can't pass it anywhere, or at least I'm lacking the correct syntax.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: If you know that you have exactly one generic parameter, you may want to use `Single()`.

Comment: Easiest way would be to put an interface on your DefaultController and use that instead (hopefully, you don't need to know the generic). Otherwise, what are you really trying to accomplish? The solution depends on it because you might be forced to use reflection or not.

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by "I can't pass it". You get an instance of `System.Type`, what do you try to do with it?

Comment: If you are going to drive some additional action based on the class name of the controller, why not simplify the implementation and require the DefaultController implementer to override a readonly enum (or other data type) property that is used to control the behavior instead? This approach could also play nicely with mocking.

Comment: You can always cast to `Controller` (instead of `DefaultController<T>`). Do you need specific methods or properties from DefaultController?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is instructive to understand why this is impossible.

```
public abstract partial class DefaultController<T> : Controller where T : IBaseEntity { ... }
public class WorkflowController : DefaultController<Workflow> { ... }
```

Here, let me rewrite that:

```
class Container { }
class Animal { }
class Fish : Animal { }
class Cage<T> : Container where T : Animal 
{ 
  public T Contents { get; set; }
}
class Aquarium : Cage<Fish> { }
```

The question now is, what happens when I have:

```
Aquarium a = new Aquarium(); // Fine
Cage<Fish> cf = a; // Fine
Container c = a; // Fine
Cage<Animal> ca1 = a; // Nope
Cage<Animal> ca2 = a as Cage<Animal>; // Null!
```

Why is this disallowed?  Well, suppose it were allowed.

```
Cage<Animal> ca = a; // Suppose this is legal
Tiger t = new Tiger(); // Another kind of animal.
ca.Contents = t; // Cage<Animal>.Contents is of type Animal, so this is legal
```

And we just put a tiger into an aquarium. That's why this is illegal.

As Jon Skeet says, a bowl of apples is not a bowl of fruit.  You can put a banana into a bowl of fruit, but you can't put a banana into a bowl of apples, and therefore they are different types!

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with a *class* (i.e. DefaultController), but if you want to extract out the parts you need into an *interface*, then it can be made variant. Here's a covariant example:

```
public interface IEntityController<out T> where T : IBaseEntity
{

}

public abstract partial class DefaultController<T>: Controller, IEntityController<T> 
    where T : IBaseEntity
{

}
```

Use it like this:

```
    var controller = filterContext.Controller as IEntityController<IBaseEntity>;
```

However, note that you'll be forced to decide whether your interface is covariant or contravariant: do you only have methods that take IBaseEntity values as parameters, or do you only have methods that return them? If you do both, then it simply isn't safe to assume that you can call those methods for subclasses of your default controller.

If, on the other hand, you don't even need the generic parameter in any of your method signatures, you could simplify things further and make your interface non-generic:

```
public interface IEntityController
{

}

public abstract partial class DefaultController<T>: Controller, IEntityController
    where T : IBaseEntity
{

}
```

...

```
    var controller = filterContext.Controller as IEntityController;
```